# GLUT animation with glTimerFunc

Tags: c, opengl, freeglut

I've been trying out some simple drawings and animations with freeglut (on Linux in virtual machine). Until now everything built and worked just fined. My latest try was moving a square around with `glTimerFunc`. Although it built without any errors with `gcc stack.c -lGL -lglut -o stack`, the animation itself doesn't work. I've looked at every example of an animation with glut I could find, but didn't see any problems with my code. Could anyone explain to me what my mistake is?

(edit: see below for working code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

int dx = 0;

#define TIMERSECS 100

void animate(int value) {
  glutTimerFunc(TIMERSECS, animate, 1);
  if (dx > 0.5) {
    dx = -0.5;
  }
  else {
    dx += 0.1;
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.5);

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2d(-0.5+dx, 0.5);
    glVertex2d(-0.5+dx, -0.5);
    glVertex2d(0.5+dx, -0.5);
    glVertex2d(0.5+dx, 0.5);
  glEnd();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void initialize(void) {
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
  glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

  initialize();
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutTimerFunc(TIMERSECS, animate, 0);
  glutPostRedisplay();

  glutMainLoop();
}
```

EDIT

@datenwolf: I looked at the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072951/simple-2d-animation-in-glut) you answered more carefully this time and took some of the code from there, works great!

Here's the new version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

int factor=100; // factor the animation is slowed down by

double dx = 0;

void animate(double speed);

static double ftime(void) {
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);

    return 1.0*t.tv_sec + 1e-6*t.tv_usec;
}

static double last_T;

static void idle(void) {
  const double now_T = ftime();
  const double delta_T = now_T - last_T;
  last_T = now_T;

  const double speed = delta_T * 60;

  animate(speed);

  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void animate(double speed) {
  if (dx > 1.5) {
    dx = -1.5;
  }
  else {
    dx += speed/factor;
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.5);

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2d(-0.5+dx, 0.5);
    glVertex2d(-0.5+dx, -0.5);
    glVertex2d(0.5+dx, -0.5);
    glVertex2d(0.5+dx, 0.5);
  glEnd();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void initialize(void) {
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
  glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

  initialize();
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutIdleFunc(idle);
  glutPostRedisplay();

  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Dankeschön für deine Hilfe!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use a event timer for animation. Instead you should call glutPostDisplay from the idle function and measure the time between calls to the display function and base the animation time on this.

Comment: Do you mean [glutPostRedisplay](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html)? Should I animate using glutIdleFunc? (Which I tried, but didn't work either)

Comment: @teashorts: You should call glutPostRedisplay in the idle function, or register it itself as idle function. Then you measure the time between display function calls; use a global variable for this.